# Angularjs UI-Router Issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So here I have my index.html and app.js. I'm trying to use prismjs to show a code block on my view .If you run the snippet below me. This is how I like my app to do. But in my real app I'd like to not include a  tag that contain my secondview.html. I would like it to be in its own separate file. But when I do that the prism css file won't work inside the ui-view.

Is there any configuration I would have to do? I believe it has something to do with the ng-binding.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CBUl.png) is what it looks like inside the ui-view. I wish I can provide another link to show you what it looks like outside the ui-view but I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links...lol But it just pretty much has all of the classes that the prism js injected into the elements which the prism.css will render.

[This is what it looks like when the view is in its own separate file(Not Working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFr4w.png)

The Code below me has the secondview.html inside the index.html(Works)

```js
myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'secondview.html'
  });
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
<!--    <meta charset="utf-8" />-->
    <title>AngularJS Prism</title>  
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.4.1/themes/prism.min.css">
    
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: grey">


<h1>Firsts View(Not Inside ui-view)</h1>
    
<pre>
<code class="language-html">
&lt;html>
  &lt;head>
    &lt;title>Test&lt;/title>
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  &lt;/head>
  &lt;body>
    &lt;div class="container">
      &lt;p>Hello There this is a short test&lt;/p>
    &lt;/div>
    &lt;script src="javascripts/app.js">&lt;/script>
  &lt;/body>
&lt;/html>
</code>
</pre>
    
    
    
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="secondview.html">
    
    <h1>Second View(Inside ui-view)</h1>

<pre>
<code class="language-html">
  
  
  
&lt;html>
  &lt;head>
    &lt;title>Test&lt;/title>
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  &lt;/head>
  &lt;body>
    &lt;div class="container">
      &lt;p>Hello There this is a short test&lt;/p>
    &lt;/div>
    &lt;script src="javascripts/app.js">&lt;/script>
  &lt;/body>
&lt;/html>
  
  
</code>
</pre>
    
    
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <div ui-view></div>
    
    
    <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.4.1/prism.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Need a `directive`** :

```
  .directive('ngPrism', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        Prism.highlightElement(element.find('code')[0]);
      }
    }
  })
```

Then **wrap your code html by `<div ng-prism> ... </div>`**:

```
    <div ng-prism>
        <pre>
        <code class="language-html">
        &lt;html>
          &lt;head>
            &lt;title>Test&lt;/title>
            &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
          &lt;/head>
          &lt;body>
            &lt;div class="container">
              &lt;p>Hello There this is a short test&lt;/p>
            &lt;/div>
            &lt;script src="javascripts/app.js">&lt;/script>
          &lt;/body>
        &lt;/html>
        </code>
        </pre>
    </div>
```

**Then it worked.**

[Plunder demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bdjtCuExa4B3SPftvXxl?p=preview).